# How to redirect http traffic through router/firewall to the transparent squid proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, router, iptables, squid

I installed Squid proxy on a different network than my LAN. 
I inserted "http_port 3128 transparent" on “/etc/squid3/squid.conf” and I added the following iptable rule on router/firewall:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth00 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to &IP_PROXY:3128
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth00 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

eth00 is the network interface associated to my LAN.
Router/firewall is between my LAN, PROXY and internet. I won't install Squid on my LAN if possible.

The iptables rules don't work and proxy can't intercept the traffic.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I changed "transparent" with "accel allow-direct" and "-i eth0" with "-s &IP_LAN"